# Xampp Object not found! error, cannot publish a new post

Tags: laravel, xampp

I installed laravel 5.7 on XAMPP. Now, when I want to publish a post. I am getting the bellow error. Please help. Thanks in advance. 
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

```
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<form method = "POST" action = "/posts">

    {{ csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type=""text" class="form-control" id="title"name = "title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body:</label>
        <textarea id = "body" name = "body" class = "form-control"></textarea>
    </div> 

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>

</form>
```

Comment: The from url is  `http://localhost/blog/public/posts/create`, but once I fill up the from  and click on publish button, it takes me to `http://localhost/posts` url.

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file in the project directory? If not create one then add `APP_DEBUG=true` this will turn on debugging, which will give you a meaningful error message.

Comment: Hi Lex, yes,I have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by `<form method = "POST" action="{{ route('posts') }}>`

My Route here `Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using "laravelcollective/html", If yes kindly try to set up the virtual host to the public path of the project and try again

OR

instead to laravelcollective Form tag, use simple form tag and give action="http://localhost/blog/public/posts/create"

Also, request you to please put all form tag code here, so can debug easily. Hope your issue will be solved.

Comment: Hi Amol, I'm not using "laravelcollective/html", it is just a normal laravel project/blog

Answer (score 0):

Make your project inside `htdocs` folder

You're got an error because the object really doesn't exist in your *htdocs* directory.

htdocs (or www) is the directory that the Apache web server looks for files to serve on your domain by default.

Comment: Hi Udhav, I created the project inside htdocs directory during installation.

Comment: check .htaccess in your public directory?

Comment: In my .htaccess, I have this  `# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Copy all code and paste your .htaccess file

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I replaced .htaccess code with this code but didn't work at all. Should I replace only # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...  part with your code?

Comment: This is my current .htaccess file.  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews 
  </IfModule>
 
   RewriteEngine On
   
   # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder... 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
 
 # Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

Comment: @ShamimaSaleem No problem in your `.htaccess` file